# Question on Limits - Asymptote

Tags: limits

As $x$ gets larger, $(x^3-8)/(x^2-4)$ approaches

a. 0

b. 1

c. 2

d. 3

e. infinity.

The answer is 3 but I do not think it is correct. Shouldn't it be infinity as we will have a slanted asymptote?

Comment: yeah bruh it's definitely (e).

Comment: do you think it meant as x approached 2?

Comment: ^because the limit as x approaches 2 is 3

Comment: (x^3-8)/(x^2-4) = ((x-2)(x^2+2x+4))/((x-2)(x+2)) = (x^2+2x+4)/(x+2) = (4+4+4)/4 = 3

Comment: but it's only a limit, because if you actually try to divide (x^3-8)/(x^2-4) you'll get 0/0

Comment: there was a typo in the question! it meant to say as x approached 2, not infinity.

Comment: as to the cubic, it is a general rule that $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Comment: $a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2...b^{n-1})$

Answer (score 1):

We have an $x^3$ in the numerator and an $x^2$ in the denominator. $x^3$ increases much faster than $x^2$, so as $x$ gets large, the fraction will approach infinity.